# Grails json using list

Tags: java, json, grails, groovy

My Domain Class is declared as
    I m using Grails 1.3.7

```
StudentReport{
  String username
  String studentName
}

 def sp = StudentReport.createCriteria()



def studentReportList = sp.list {

            projections {
               property 'username'
                property 'studentName'
            }
            firstResult 0
            maxResults 20
            order("id", "asc")
        } 
render studentReportList as JSON

My expected result is

[
{"username":"13B06","student_name":"JOHN SAMUEL"},
{"username":"13B07","student_name":"KATHIRESAN.K"},
{"username":"13B08","student_name":"KATHIRESAN.K"},
{"username":"13B11","student_name":"MALINI.S"}
]

But what i get is

[
   ["13B06","JOHN SAMUEL"],
   ["13B07","KATHIRESAN.K"],
   ["13B08","KATHIRESAN.K"],
   ["13B11","MALINI.S"]
]
```

I need property name along with curly braces. Could any one help me out.
I have tried without using projections in my controller, then i was getting the exact result but if i try using projections, then i held up in getting the same results.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ {"13B06","JOHN SAMUEL"},{"13B07","KATHIRESAN.K"},{"13B08","KATHIRESAN.K"},{"13B11","MALINI.S"} ]
```

is not valid JSON.  The output you are currently getting is correct, because `studentReportList` is a List of Lists, so the JSON must be an array of arrays.  If you want braces then the inner elements would need to be JSON *objects* rather than arrays.  To generate

```
[
  {"username":"13B06","student_name":"JOHN SAMUEL"},
  ...
]
```

you could add a suitable result transformer to your criteria and use the two-argument form of the `property` projection method to assign the right aliases:

```
def studentReportList = sp.list{
        projections {
           property 'username', 'username'
            property 'studentName', 'student_name'
        }
        firstResult 0
        maxResults 20
        order("id", "asc")
        resultTransformer AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE
    }
```

(along with the [appropriate import](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.html)) to make the criteria return a List of Maps rather than a List of Lists.

Comment: i have reedited my question. should i use json builder instead or which import library,

Comment: could i know the exact import library. Im getting [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}] as a result using import org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer

Comment: @AmarnathaliasRoobal The import has been added to the answer which is part of hibernate so you would not need extra library. What you would need in addition to the above is to set an alias for the properties as `property 'username', 'username'`

Comment: @AmarnathaliasRoobal try it with the two-argument form of `property` - I've edited with an example.

Comment: No such property error AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder without using import . I m using grails 1.3.7 version

Comment: @AmarnathaliasRoobal you still need the `import` as well.

Comment: @Ian Roberts using property 'username', 'username' i got the result